# Warning when using pages field to sort bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I have a great number of citations from a single author in the same year and to process that properly, I created my own custom sorting scheme in biblatex (style windycity). I seems to work as intended, but it nevertheless gives warnings about my use of the pages field. I am wondering if I'm doing something wrong, or else if I can turn off the warnings as it obscures more important warnings.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=windycity, 
    uniquename=false, 
    sorting=nytvp, 
    date=year
    ]{biblatex}
    \DeclareSortingScheme{nytvp}{
        \sort{
            \field{presort}
        }
        \sort[final]{
            \field{sortkey}
        }
        \sort{
            \field{sortname}
            \field{author}
            \field{editor}
            \field{translator}
            \field{journaltitle}
            \field{title}
        }
        \sort{
            \field{sortyear}
            \field{year}
        }
        \sort{
            \field{sorttitle}
            \field{journaltitle}
            \field{booktitle}
            \field{title}
        }
        \sort{
            \field{volume}
        }
        \sort{
            \field{number}
        }       
        \sort{
            \field{pages}
        }
    }
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives 102 of the following warnings when running biber:

> WARN - Unknown field 'pages' found in sorting template

Comment: `pages` is a range field and therefore a bit special. But you'd think you could make this work. Open an issue at the Biber bugtracker to ask about this message: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues

Comment: Oh that's a good suggestion, I'll try it there too.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, here is the github issue I opened: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/353